# Orthography changes in Italian

Tags: reference-request, orthography, italian

How has the orthography of Italian changed in the 19th century? I’m trying to find an in-depth guide but I haven’t found any resources. Maybe it just hasn’t changed except for a few technical words?

Comment: One issue is that at the start of the 19th century, Italy had not been unified, and what would became standard Italian was then really Florentine Tuscan (think Dante). With unification, some words from other Italian languages/dialects were incorporated into standard Italian, and that might appear as orthographic change.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, there's a nice overview on [the Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/lingua-dell-ottocento_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) on the *Ottocento* and on the [history of Italian orthography](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ortografia_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/), with good references to the increasing rates of literacy among the middle classes and an overview of 19th century spelling reform.

Key takeaways are:

- The use of *j* is still present, but inconsistent. The spellings *gioja* for modern standard *gioia*, *jeri* for *ieri*, and also the use of *j* for final -*ii* are all attested, e.g. *studj* for *studii*.
- Which consonants are doubled (which reflects the irregular phonological changes of the borrowings, including those from academic Neo Latin and Greek) is not yet standardised, so we have *occorono* for *occorrono*, *piutosto* for *piuttosto*, *academia* for *accademia*. The latter is the main debate between the [*manzonismi*](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/manzonismi_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/), proponents of a more phonetic spelling, and *classicisti*, with etymological spelling preferred.
- The use of capital letters is still in flux: either all nouns (like modern German spelling); or at the beginnings of sentences, and for the 'proper' nouns to capitalise (the definition of which then has to be made - in the modern spelling, yes for names of individual people and places, but no to the days of the week, to demonyms, to language names).
- Use of the apostrophe is still in flux.
- Use of the hyphen for compound words varies.
- Use of the *h diacritica* changes, i.e. *à*, *ànno* for modern *ha*, *hanno* is still attested, but declines during the period.

Compare:

- Maraschio, Nicoletta (1993) [*Grafia e ortografia: evoluzione e codificazione*](https://flore.unifi.it/handle/2158/230187)
- Michel (2012) [*Italian orthography in Early Modern times*](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110288179.63)

Comment: _À_ was presumably equivalent to _ha_, not _ho_?